# How to configure GRUB to load Windows 7 Install in UEFI mode

Tags: windows, system-installation, grub2, uefi

I have a Dual-Boot USB I created with [Multisystem](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CEAQFjAB&url=http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/&ei=_CL3TpTkCornrAfNn8EC&usg=AFQjCNE-RmPVXwRjYjKANWdT_vACIL02BA) for booting into PartedMagic, Ubuntu 11.10 & Windows 7 Install. Problem is Windows 7 says it can't install on a GPT partition.

Googled, and found that I need an UEFI system (on [ASUS H67M-PRO](http://www.asus.com/Motherboards/Intel_Socket_1155/P8H67M_PRO/), supports UEFI BIOS, so this shouldn't be the problem). I also need to have the correct efi files. I find efi files in my USB, so I think that's fine. But I think the files might not be loaded or something?

So I am thinking, do I need to do something special to boot into the UEFI installer for Windows 7 or something? For that I need to configure the GRUB on the USB? How?

Comment: You're a lot more likely to have better luck eschewing `grub` altogether. UEFI + boot loader = unnecessary redundancy. See [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/146803/52934).

Answer (score -1):

You need to reinstall the system and make sure that you boot the Ubuntu install media in EFI mode.  This will prompt it to create the EFI system partition ( if you tell it to use the entire disk ) and install the EFI version of grub.

Comment: How do I install Ubuntu in EFI mode? I wasn't asked about the EFI partition, and dont have one

Comment: @jiewmeng, by having your bios boot the cd in EFI mode.  You will get a grub menu instead of the usual syslinux boot menu.

Comment: This is incorrect in almost every sense. You do not need to do this from the install media, and there is no such thing as a BIOS booting in EFI mode.

Comment: @mikeserv, Sure, you *could* manually move partitions around, add an EFI system partition and swap out the boot loader rather than simply reinstall it right in the first place, though this would still require the use of some sort of live media.  That doesn't make the answer "wrong in almost every sense".  Also while you might make the pedantic argument that I should have said "configure your system firmware to boot in EFI mode", most people understand the word BIOS better, and it is commonly used in that generic sense of system firmware rather than specifically referring to the IBM PC BIOS.