# How to write/edit/update the OsIndications efi variable from command line?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, uefi, firmware

In the need to enter the UEFI firmware setup utility while using ultra fast boot (keyboard drivers are not loaded during POST), I wish to write to the "Os Indications" efi variable. My OS is Ubuntu 14.04 kernel 3.13.0-35-generic.

> `OsIndications` variable returns a UINT64 bitmask
>
> `OsIndicationsSupported` variable returns a UINT64 bitmask
>
> The `EFI_OS_INDICATIONS_BOOT_TO_FW_UI` bit can be set in the
>   OsIndicationsSupported variable by the firmware, if the firmware
>   supports OS requests to stop at a firmware user interface. The
>   `EFI_OS_INDICATIONS_BOOT_TO_FW_UI` bit can be set by the OS in the
>   OsIndications variable, if the OS desires for the firmware to stop at
>   a firmware user interface on the next boot.
>
> `EFI_OS_INDICATIONS_BOOT_TO_FW_UI`=`0x0000000000000001` - [Page 312 of UEFI spec
>   2.3.1C](http://www.uefi.org/sites/default/files/resources/UEFI_2_3_1_C.pdf)

My firmware has the ability to enter the firmware setup utility at next boot:

```
$ hexdump /sys/firmware/efi/vars/OsIndicationsSupported-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c/data
0000000 0001 0000 0000 0000
0000008
```

I can create a new variable on `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` using

```
$ printf\x07\x00\x00\x00\x00" > myvar-12345678-1234-1234-1234-123456789abc
```

However writing to the efi variable `OsIndications-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c` results in all sorts of `write error: Invalid argument`:

#### Using new efivarfs

```
# printf "x00\x00\x00\x01" > /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/OsIndications-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
-bash: printf: write error: Invalid argument

# printf "x00\x00\x00\x01" > /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/OsIndications-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
-bash: printf: write error: Invalid argument

# printf "\x01" > /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/OsIndications-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
-bash: printf: write error: Invalid argument

# cat enter-uefi-fw > /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/OsIndications-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
cat: write error: Invalid argument
```

#### Using old 1024 byte maximum sysfs-efivars

```
# cat enter-uefi-fw > /sys/firmware/efi/vars/OsIndications-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c/raw_var
cat: write error: Input/output error

# cat enter-uefi-fw > /sys/firmware/efi/vars/new_var
cat: write error: Invalid argument

# echo 'enter-uefi-fw' > /sys/firmware/efi/vars/OsIndications-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c/raw_var
-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument

# printf "\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" > /sys/firmware/efi/vars/OsIndications-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c/raw_var
-bash: printf: write error: Invalid argument
```

#### Checked the requirements for UEFI variables support to work properly

1. EFI Runtime Services support should be present in the kernel
   `$ cat /boot/config-$(uname -r) | grep CONFIG_EFI=y` returns `CONFIG_EFI=y`
2. Kernel processor bitness/arch and EFI processor bitness/arch should match
    
   ?
3. Kernel should be booted in EFI mode
   CSM is disabled in Firmware setup utility/BIOS
4. EFI runtime services in the kernel should not be disabled via kernel cmdline, i.e. noefi kernel parameter should not be used.
   `cat /proc/cmdline | grep EFI` returns nothing
5. efivarfs filesystem should be mounted at /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
   `mount | grep efivars` returns `none on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw)`
6. `efivar -l` should list the EFI Variables without any error
    The command lists 82 lines and no errors.
7. Check for existence of /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/dump-* files.
   No dump- files exist there.

According to https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/8264/after-installing-fedora-i-cant-open-biosefi-setup/?answer=16402#post-id-16402 the `cat enter-uefi-fw > /sys/firmware/efi/vars/new_var` command should work in Fedora 17.

#### First deleting OsIndications doesn't improve

```
# rm -rv /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/OsIndications-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c
removed '/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/OsIndications-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c'
# ls -l enter-uefi-fw
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2084 Aug 25 20:23 enter-uefi-fw
# cat enter-uefi-fw > /sys/firmware/efi/vars/new_var
cat: write error: Invalid argument
```

How can I update the already existing OsIndications efi variable in Ubuntu 14.04 (trusty) from the command-line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Due to the presence of numerous firmware bugs where removing
non-standard UEFI variables causes the system firmware to fail to POST,
*efivarfs* files that are not well-known standardized variables are
created as immutable files.

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/efivarfs.txt

This can be verified and changed with the *lsattr* and *chattr* commands.

For example:

```
root@hi12:/tmp/test# hexdump -C out 
00000000  07 00 00 00 10 00 00 00                           |........|
00000008
root@hi12:/tmp/test# cp out /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/BootSelectVariable-944fb13b-773f-4cbb-9c6f-326cebde4c23 
cp: cannot create regular file '/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/BootSelectVariable-944fb13b-773f-4cbb-9c6f-326cebde4c23': Operation not permitted
root@hi12:/tmp/test# lsattr  /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/BootSelectVariable-944fb13b-773f-4cbb-9c6f-326cebde4c23 
----i-------------- /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/BootSelectVariable-944fb13b-773f-4cbb-9c6f-326cebde4c23
root@hi12:/tmp/test# chattr -i /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/BootSelectVariable-944fb13b-773f-4cbb-9c6f-326cebde4c23 
root@hi12:/tmp/test# lsattr  /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/BootSelectVariable-944fb13b-773f-4cbb-9c6f-326cebde4c23 
------------------- /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/BootSelectVariable-944fb13b-773f-4cbb-9c6f-326cebde4c23
root@hi12:/tmp/test# cp out /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/BootSelectVariable-944fb13b-773f-4cbb-9c6f-326cebde4c23 
root@hi12:/tmp/test# chattr +i /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/BootSelectVariable-944fb13b-773f-4cbb-9c6f-326cebde4c23 
root@hi12:/tmp/test# lsattr  /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/BootSelectVariable-944fb13b-773f-4cbb-9c6f-326cebde4c23 
----i-------------- /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/BootSelectVariable-944fb13b-773f-4cbb-9c6f-326cebde4c23
root@hi12:/tmp/test#
```

Answer (score 2):

The relevant 64-bit mask here is:

```
  #define EFI_OS_INDICATIONS_BOOT_TO_FW_UI 0x0000000000000001
```

This can be produced as a little-endian (Intel) format string using:

```
  str='\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'; printf "$str"
```

The output of `printf "$str"` above needs to go into the **data contents** of the efivarfs variable file `$var`, where

```
  var='/sys/firmware/efi/efivars/OsIndications-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c'
```

However, each file in `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` begins with a **4-byte header** and is then followed by its data contents.  Therefore, the output of `printf "$str"` needs to prefixed with the 4-byte header before we can write it onto the efivarfs variable file `$var`.  With `$str` and `$var` as above, this can be done, e.g., using:

```
  { head -c 4 "$var"; printf "$str"; } > "$var"
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using `echo` instead of `cat`.

```
# echo 'enter-uefi-fw' > /sys/firmware/efi/vars/OsIndications-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c/raw_var
```

Comment: kernel 3.13.0-35-generic and 3.17.0-031700rc7-generic output: `-bash: echo: write error: Invalid argument`

Comment: Looking more carefully at the list of things you tried, have you tried: `printf "\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" > /sys/firmware/efi/vars/OsIndications-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c/raw_var`

?
note the leading '\' in printf '\x' that you omitted, the fact that we're filling in the entire value, and the raw_var at the end of the path.

Comment: `# printf "\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00" > /sys/firmware/efi/vars/OsIndications-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c/raw_var` results in `-bash: printf: write error: Invalid argument`

Comment: Did you download http://pjones.fedorapeople.org/enter-uefi-fw before running the `cat` command?

Comment: Yes, I did download the enter-uefi-fw data file, and that file is in my current working directory: `# ls -l enter-uefi-fw` returns
`-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2084 Aug 25 20:23 enter-uefi-fw`.

Comment: The issue for creating a new OsIndications UEFI variable might be that it is already there: `# ls -l /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/OsIndications-*` returns `-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12 Oct  3 22:39 /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/OsIndications-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c`