# ArchLinux: Error installing grub on encrypted lvm partition(lvm on luks)

Tags: arch-linux, lvm, grub, luks

I am trying to install Arch Linux on an encrypted partition (LVM on LUKS).
I followed the [relevant Arch Wiki guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dm-crypt/Encrypting_an_entire_system#LVM_on_LUKS), but when I do:

```
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
```

it gives me this output:

```
grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of 'airootfs`
```

Then I tried to do:

```
arch-chroot /mnt /bin/bash
grub-install --recheck /dev/sda
```

And it gives me this output:

```
grub-install: warning: Attempting to install GRUB to a disk with multiple partition labels. This is not supported yet..
grub-install: warning: Embedding is not possible. GRUB can only be installed in this setup by using bloclists. However, blocklists are UNRELIABLE and their use is discouraged..
grub-install: error: will not proceed with blocklists
```

I tried to follow the bootloader page on the wiki, but I don't understand what I have to do very well. Below is a screenshot showing the output of `lsblk` (I can't copy/paste because I don't want to shut down my machine during installation):

[image: lsblk output]

I think the `loop0` was created when I did  `grub-install --recheck /dev/sda` but I am not sure about this.

Comment: you'd do better to [uninstall grub](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/250068/52934)

Comment: Indeed you should change root _before_ installing GRUB. Also are you installing on EFI mode or legacy mode? If possible, post the exact commands you are typing in your setup process (yes, all of them). Please ping me with the `@Marc.2377` notation if you do